# How do I re-initialize jQuery file upload data array?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm using [jQuery file upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) in my web site for users to upload there Photos. Following is my JS code calling file upload plugin, (Please have a look at code comments as well...)

```
$('#fileupload').click(function(){  
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'productpage/uploadphoto?design='+ globalVars.selectedDesignId,
        prependFiles: true,
        start: function(){
            $("#pp-photo-area").show();
        },
        done: function (e, data) {
            console.log(data); // Only gives me new file data
            loadPhotoStudio(data); //Data is sent to another function
        }           
    }); 
});
```

And each time a user uploads a file it get added to the data array with the old file data in it, which I dont want to happen. I want it to replace the previous data array with the new one. So that I can use this data in loadPhotoStudio() function.

```
var loadPhotoStudio = function(data) {
  $('#test').click(function(){
        $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
            console.log(file.name) //This gives me all files uploaded
        });
    });   
}
```

How do I refresh data array before each upload?

Answer (score 1):

try to add this to the 'done' queue:

```
reset_field($('#fileupload'));
```

Corresponding to this function

```
function reset_field (e) {
        e.wrap('<form>').parent('form').trigger('reset');
        e.unwrap();
}
```